# show the result of total in mysqli and php

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to show the result of total value between quantity and price

```
<?php
$query_nominal = "SELECT SUM(quantity*(SELECT shpp.buy_price FROM oc_stock_hpp shpp WHERE shpp.product_id = p.product_id  ORDER BY shpp.id DESC LIMIT 1)) as total FROM oc_product p WHERE status IN ('1','2','3')";
$result_nominal = mysqli_query($koneksi, $query_nominal);
$total_nilai_transaksi = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_nominal);
?>
<body>
<?php echo "Rp " . number_format((float)$total_nilai_transaksi, 0, ',', '.'); ?>
</body>
```

But the result is this

```
Rp 1
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You fetch the recordset but you have not accessed an individual record, so `$total_nilai_transaksi` does not contain a specific value for `total` - it is an array

Comment: the `$total_nilai_transaksi` represents one row of data, and not a number. You should try `$total_nilai_transaksi['total']` instead in your `number_format`.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use the number format function on an array. This doesn't work normally, so I see you are trying to force the type to change into a float. Since PHP is weird, arrays become 1 when turned into floats. This is why you get "Rp 1" as your output.

To fix your issue, you need to access the actual value of "total". This can be done by like so:

```php
<?php echo "Rp " . number_format($total_nilai_transaksi["total"], 0, ',', '.'); ?>
```